# rundeck ansible module - No matched nodes

Tags: ansible, rundeck

system: centos 6.8 x86_64 , ansible-2.1 , rundeck-2.6.8
Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin v1.3.0

rundeck runs on the same ansible controller host, and i just want to run the playbooks from rundeck interface.

su rundeck -c "ansible all -m ping"  , works well, but when i try to run playbooks from rundeck there's an error:

Execution failed: 10: No matched nodes: MultiNodeSelector{nodenames=[localhost]}

in the jobs the node selection is "Execute locally", on the second option "Dispatch to Nodes" there's no hosts on the list. the hosts specified in the ansible playbooks, so i don't raelly need to specify it to rundeck, am i missing something here? rundeck should run the playbooks on the same host, and the ansible will deploy to the remote systems.

Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 1):

Rundeck keeps its own internal inventory of the hosts, separate from Ansible. The plugin gives you a [Resource Model Source](https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin#resource-model-source) to have Rundeck use your Ansible inventory to scan for nodes and populate the Rundeck inventory. You then configure your Rundeck job against the Rundeck inventory.

The plugin uses the defaults, so if you store your inventory in a different place than `/etc/ansible/hosts` on the Rundeck system, you will need to pass that as a parameter to the Resource Model Source like so:

[image: Rundeck Ansible Resource Model Source Custom Inventory]

Another solution would be to create a Rundeck job that merely acts as a wrapper for calling `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` and put that as a workflow step:

```
cd <your ansible dir>

. env/bin/activate # we use virtualenv
export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/var/lib/rundeck/.ansible.cfg
ansible-playbook -i inventory -l "$RD_OPTION_LIMIT" $RD_OPTION_ANSIBLE_OPTS playbooks/$RD_OPTION_PLAYBOOK
```

Something like this wouldn't require the rundeck-ansible-plugin as you can configure the Rundeck job options to suit your Ansible argument needs.

Comment: The ansible hosts file is in his default location (/etc/ansible/hosts), i tried to run as a shell script or command and it's failed with the same reason  --  (ERROR grails.app.services.rundeck.services.ExecutionUtilService - Execution failed: 16: No matched nodes: MultiNodeSelector{nodenames=[localhost]}) -- so it's seems to be some settings with rundeck service (i'm new with rundeck)

Comment: @user3820425 have you tailed your Rundeck logs to see if there's an error during the inventory scan?

Comment: from rundeck logs: -----    2016-07-11 22:08:18,942 [quartzScheduler_Worker-2] WARN  grails.app.services.rundeck.services.FrameworkService - Empty node list
2016-07-11 22:08:18,971 [quartzScheduler_Worker-2] ERROR grails.app.services.rundeck.services.ExecutionUtilService - Execution failed: 16: No matched nodes: MultiNodeSelector{nodenames=[localhost]}

Comment: @user3820425 that appears to be the log output from your job execution, not your Rundeck inventory scan where Rundeck uses your Ansible inventory to scan for nodes.  I'd like to DM/chat with you, but you need 20 rep. :(

Comment: yes, this logs appears in rundeck.log after job execution. the rundeckd service loading seems fine without errors ------ Starting Rundeck 2.6.8-1...  using rdeck.base config property: /var/lib/rundeck ... loaded configuration: /etc/rundeck/framework.properties .. RSS feeds disabled ... Rundeck is ACTIVE: executions can be run. .. Rundeck startup finished in 399ms ----- also i don't see files with pattern /tmp/rundeck/ansible-hosts*

Comment: @user3820425 glad it was a simple fix! :)